# JavaScript (not jQuery) Find class and add new class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find if a class name exists in a webpage, and then add a new class.

Testing in Chrome Developer Tools Console I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Code I am using.

```
const srtClass = document.querySelectorAll('.sr-only'); 
srtClass.className += " showoffScreenText";
console.log(srtClass);
```

The results for the console.log

> HTMLCollection(2) [span.sr-only, div.sr-only] className: "undefined showoffScreenText"

The sr-only class is found so why is it undefined?

Answer (score 1):

"querySelectorAll" returns a NodeList, you should get the first element

```
srtClass = document.querySelectorAll('.sr-only')[0]
```

Comment: Simpler is to use `querySelector`

Comment: @Barmar  thanks, that works for the first class found <span class="sr-only showoffScreenText">Home Page</span>

Comment: How do I add the new class to all instances of sr-only?

Comment: Use a loop to process all of them